# populating an ExtGWT tree via RequestFactory

Tags: gwt, gxt, requestfactory

I upgraded to GWT 2.2.0 with RequestFactory - I have a TreePanel and I want to get some ModelData instances from server to populate it.

If I use ValueProxies, can I return the ModelData instances from server?

I heard RequestFactory support will come in ExtGWT 3.0 - but until then, is there any way to use RF to populate a TreePanel?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?122282-BeanModel-generation-with-AutoBean-support

The answer also is here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?125509-Mapping-GWT-RequestFactory-proxies-to-GXT-components